# Use locale for specific number instances

Tags: formatting, punctuation, locale

I am trying to display some numbers using a locale that formats them with dots as thousands separator and commas as decimal separators: `19.003,41`.

Accordingly to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82009/babel-and-the-decimal-separator) it can be done with `babel`, but I don't really want to use it throughout the entire document, I just want to be able to wrap the desired number in some tag that formats it

For example, for the number from above, I wonder if there is some way where you can do something like

```
\locale_number{19003.41}
```

and get the result `19.003,41` in the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could perhaps load `siunitx` and use

```
\num[group-separator={.},output-decimal-marker={,}]{19003.41}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\num[group-separator={.},output-decimal-marker={,}]{19003.41} 
\end{document}
```