# pgfplotstable: dec sep = {.} doesn't work as expected

Tags: pdftex, pgfplotstable

I need to use the point "." as a decimal separator, but something strange happens, I write:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2,dec sep={n}}
\pgfmathprintnumber{12.3456}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2,dec sep={.}}
\pgfmathprintnumber{12.3456}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2,dec sep={,}}
\pgfmathprintnumber{12.3456}
\end{document}
```

[image]

the first one works as expected, but the others only show me the comma, why does this happen? am i forgetting something?, I tried also with `use period`,but it is the same.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please provide a complete yet minimal example that starts with `\documentcass`, ends with `\end{document}`, can be compiled and shows this issue? (Did you try `use comma=false`?)

Comment: Sure @Schrödinger'scat, I'll prepare it

Comment: Use `\usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot, es-tabla]{babel}`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82013. That is, add the option `es-nodecimaldot` to `babel`.

Comment: Yes, see my above comment: load `babel` with the `es-nodecimaldot` option.

Comment: it was what I needed, now it works, thanks! @Schrödinger'scat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to change the comma everywhere in your document to a period, use [Gonzalos nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82013), i.e. load `babel` with `es-nodecimaldot` option. This answer is to show how one change the decimal separator locally to a period. This works by appending `\decimalpoint` to the code of `use period`.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,use period/.append code={\decimalpoint}}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathprintnumber{12.3456}
\pgfmathprintnumber[use period]{12.3456}
\pgfmathprintnumber{12.3456}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @Schrödinger's cat, I will consider the latter